# How to create a &str from a single character?

Tags: rust

I can't believe I'm asking this frankly, but how do I create a &str (or a String) when I have a single character?

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch03-02-data-types.html

Comment: If you have an ASCII character in a `u8` (whose in-memory representation doesn't differ from a UTF-8 string that contains it), you can use [`std::slice::from_ref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/fn.from_ref.html) to create a `&str` directly from the character, without allocating an intermediate `String`: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=11fc5ebfe61639fbc2a44f46283b5b37

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting a char to &str](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47629596/converting-a-char-to-str)

Comment: People should be cautious when reading answers and comments here: a char isn't a byte and some hacks do what hacks do: they bite you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first thing to try for simple conversions is `into()`.

It works for `String` because `String` [implements](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#impl-From%3Cchar%3E) `From<char>`.

```rust
let c: char = 'π';
let s: String = c.into();
```

You can't build a `&str` directly from a char. A `&str` is a reference type. The easiest solution is to build it from a string:

```rust
let s: &str = &s;
```

---

An alternative for most kinds of values is the [`format`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.format.html) macro:

```rust
let s = format!("{}", c);
```

Answer (score 3):

If just need to use the `&str` locally and you want to avoid heap allocation, you can use `char` method [encode_utf8](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.char.html#method.encode_utf8):

```rust
fn main() {
    let c = 'n';
    let mut tmp = [0; 1];

    let foo = c.encode_utf8(&mut tmp);

    println!("str: {}", foo);
}
```

or

```rust
fn main() {
    let tmp = [b'n'; 1];

    let foo = std::str::from_utf8(&tmp).unwrap();

    println!("str: {}", foo);
}
```

To work with every char you need to use a `u8` array of length 4 `[0; 4]`. In utf8, ascii chars can be represented as a single byte, but all other characters require more bytes with maximum of 4.

This is a simplified example based on an answer from a very similar question:
[Converting a char to &str](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47629596/converting-a-char-to-str)